# How to pass a string variable from an anchor tag to a php file on click?

Tags: php, html, sql

Attempting to pass the value of an anchor tag as a string to a php file so that I can enter the string variable in a SQL search query.

```
<div class="keywords">
  <h4>By Keyword:</h4>
  <ul>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>Maecenas</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>Lorem</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>Mauris</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>Lighting</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>aliquam </li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>ipsum</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>dolor</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>Vivamus</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>scelerisque</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>eleifend</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>elit</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>sapien</li></a>
    <a href="keyword.php"><li>facilisis</li></a>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I'm assuming that I will also have to make use of regex to get rid of the li's.

Comment: Append query string behind the href like `<a href="keyword.php?keyword=Maecenas"><li>Maecenas</li></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use php in this view. for instance you could do:

```
<a href="keyword.php?keyword=<?= $keyWord?>"><li><?= $keyWord?></li></a>
```

the `<?= ?>` tag is shorthand for `echo`

or if that is out of the question then

```html
<a href="keyword.php?keyword=Maecenas"><li>Maecenas</li></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this will helps

```
<?php $string = "stringhere";?>
<a href="keyword.php?string=<?php echo $string;?>"><li>Maecenas</li></a>
```